# Lock any action on a page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, popup, html, outsystems

I am relatively new to JavaScript. I have developed an application with the Outsystems technology, where-in I present a pop-up to the user and once the user fills the information, the user clicks 'Save' button. Now I need to disable all the page contents as it takes a long time to save and in between that the user may click anything else.

So I need to lock the page using JavaScript, with a message that tells user to wait until the process finishes.(on-click of the 'Save' button)

Any hints ?

Thanks.

Comment: User [Overlay](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1823-adding-a-page-overlay-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a full page fixed position overlay that says "Saving... Please wait." on it. You might even make it semi-transparent grey.

Answer (score 1):

The absolutely dead-simple method would be a [jQueryUI modal dialog.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) You can implement one with just a few lines of code, plus a little HTML markup and including the library:

```
$( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
        height: 140,
        modal: true
    });
});
```

However, you should take note: this, *just like any other JavaScript solution,* won't stop malicious users from interacting with your site when you don't want them to. The only true protection is to check all input from the user when it reaches your serverside code.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable all inputs using JavaScript:

(in this case jQuery)

```
$(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

But likewise that would not stop the doing something in another tab, or navigating away from the page, or refreshing it.

Comment: This makes no provision for elements that were already disabled - to wit, there's no way to reverse it without enabling everything.

Comment: @sudowned that is beyond the scope of the question, no?

Comment: I disagree on the grounds that it is destructive to the form's state. This directly impacts the usefulness of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something very simple, like apply a transparent div over the top of your page.  Say like this:

```
var overlay = $("<div style='width:100%; height: 100%; top: 0; z-index: 100; position: absolute; background: lightgray; opacity: 0.5; text-align: center; font-size: large; padding-top: 25%; font-weight: bold;'>Loading...</div>");
$("body").append(overlay);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9G4bT/3/)):

CSS:

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #000;

    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}​
```

JavaScript:

```
$('<div>in process...</div>')
    .addClass('overlay')
    .fadeTo(0, 0.4)
    .appendTo('body');
​
```